# Why do web page rendering engines commonly "crash or hang"?

Tags: webkit, chromium, software-design

I am reading the [Multi-process Architecture Documentation for Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture/), and I'm curious as to what they mean in the first few paragraphs:

> It's nearly impossible to build a rendering engine that never crashes or hangs. It's also nearly impossible to build a rendering engine that is perfectly secure.

> In some ways, the state of web browsers around 2006 was like that of the single-user, co-operatively multi-tasked operating systems of the past. As a misbehaving application in such an operating system could take down the entire system, so could a misbehaving web page in a web browser. All it took was one rendering engine or plug-in bug to bring down the entire browser and all of the currently running tabs.

My question is, why is it impossible to build a web page rendering engine that never crashes or hangs? Is it because of the nature of the internet, where an engine can be asked to render a "very large" web page and consequently take up a lot of resources?